# changed wordpress address to a site i dont own by accedent, recovering it

Tags: wordpress

I was going through the 'settings' tab of my wordpress site and by accident i changed my **WordPress Address (URL)** and **Site Address (URL)** to a site i dont own (i accidentally put .com instead of .co.uk)

Now when i go to `mysite.co.uk/wp-admin` it takes me to the other site (the .com) i dont own, as you can see this is a big problem, is there a easy way i can get back into wp and change this back over ?

is there somthing i one of the wp-config.php files i could download edit and upload again, or a part of a db table i need to update ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I developing a site it I do it on a test server and then push to the live server.  To do this I change the two fields in the mySQL database.  In phpmyadmin you can change the wordpress options.

wp_options table
edit the siteurl option.
and any other instances that you want to make sure are correct.

The following query should find them.

SELECT * FROM `wp_options` WHERE option_value LIKE '%mysite.com%'

Then edit those files, be sure to make a backup of your database before you do that.  It should work but at times changing the database like that might affect things in your menu or else where on your site.  It should fix your oops and allow you in to make things right.

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines to the top of `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://mysite.co.uk');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://mysite.co.uk');
```

In `functions.php`, use these two lines:

```
update_option('siteurl','http://mysite.co.uk');
update_option('home','http://mysite.co.uk');
```

Load up http://mysite.co.uk/wp-admin, verify that you can get in, and then remove those lines from the files.

Comment: thanks, i can get in now, but the wordpress address (url) and site address (url) are both greyed out (although they now contain the correct values). can i get them to revert to how they were prior ?

Comment: Did you remove the `define` lines from the .php file?

Comment: yep, but as soon as i removed them and refreshed the settings page it jumped straigh back to the .com

Comment: just a bit more info i did this in the wp-config.php file

Comment: Check my updated answer for some additional lines to put in your `functions.php` as well

Comment: just to confirm, you do both parts not just one, and the functions.php is in the "wp-includes" folder. If so unfortunatly nothing happens, just get a blank screen, checked the source nothing loads ?

Comment: you should be editing the `functions.php` file that is in the directory for whichever theme you have activated.

Comment: ahh ok, changed them (config and theme functions) but still to no avail the settings box's are still greyed in and cant be changed

Comment: Once you `update_option`, you need to remove those lines as well.

Comment: once the update option lines are removed, i tried to refresh the page again, still greyed in. The functions file im editing is wp-content/themes/swatch/functions.php (swatch is the name of the theme)

Comment: You need to do both the `wp_config.php` and `functions.php` changes at the same time, visit `/wp-admin`, and then remove the changes at the same time.

Comment: still the same problem, grey when the changes are made, redirecting to .com when they are removed

Comment: Thanks for all the help with this. I think im going to leave it as it is standing with the greyed in boxs. That wont raise any security issue would it ?

Answer (score 1):

go to your phpmyadmin and select the table called wp_otions
change site url to your previous site http://mysite.co.uk.

it worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

Run this query in your MySQL database, with the URL changed to your actual site URL:

```
update wp_options
set option_value = 'http://example.com'
where option_name in ('siteurl', 'home');
```

NB: assumes that your WordPress tables are prefixed with 'wp_', adjust as necessary if not.